# None of my images are showing

Tags: html, css, background-image, jekyll

I am using Jekyll to create a simple site. I am trying to put a background image on the hero section through the CSS background-image property, but the image won't load. I tested a different image by trying to upload an image directly into the HTML using the  element, and that won't load either. This lead me to question if the paths were wrong, but I can't seem to find an error in my directory structure or code. I tested in firebug, and see that the error is 'failed to load the given url'. All of my images are located within the 'images' folder in my project, and I copied and pasted the actual name to make sure that I wasn't typing it wrong. Here's some of the code that is relevant.

The folder structure within my project for this section:

```
_scss (folder)
  1-tools (folder)
  2-modules (folder)
    hero.scss (scss file being edited)
  3-layouts (folder)
  images (folder)
    hero.jpg (file being called)
```

```css
.hero-section {
  background: url(../images/hero.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-section">
  <!-- background image fills the div -->
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div class="hero-talk">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can point out what I may be doing wrong, that would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem. I think it was Jekyll specific. Since all of my styles were being sent to an external CSS file in another folder, the images weren't being found at the last minute. I just moved my images folder outside of the _scss folder, so that the path is correct at the last minute when everything is pushed to the final css file.

Comment: Please upvote my comment above if that was helpful. Tnx @Tre

Comment: @Tre The problem was probably having the `images` folder inside of the `_scss` folder. Folders whose names begin with `_` are not copied to the final site. In the future, you can check if your files are present by checking the `_site` folder generated by Jekyll.

Comment: @shadowen Yeah that was the problem. I know now not to include my images there from now on.

Comment: Please update your answer to reflect this, then mark as correct :)